# Find the longest subsequence of balanced brackets in linear time

Tags: algorithm

We have 3 types of brackets: '[', '(', '{'.

It is not really hard to check if sequence of brackets is balanced but this question seems a bit trickier.

Let's consider an example: "()({[]". In this case the answer will be either "()" or "[]" (they both have length 2)

But also we have such an example: "()({[]})". In this case the answer will be this sequence itself (well, because it is balanced). But at some moment we will be iterating over subsequence that is the same as in previous example. So, how do we "merge" these answers?

To understand my struggles better let me explain.

Again, previous example. By the moment we iterated over such subsequence "()({[]" we have maximal length 2 and one of two subsequences ("[]" or "()"). But by the end we should get this: "()({[]})".

What would be preferred way to handle this brackets sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a stack of tuples with each tuple representing ( bracket, index-of-the-bracket )
and push-pop the stack in the following way:

- If you see an opening bracket push the tuple ( bracket, index )
- If you see a closing bracket and if the previous bracket on the stack is a matching opening bracket, pop the bracket and get the index of the popped tuple. And add a tuple (index-of-opening-bracket, index-of-closing-bracket) to a list of balanced brackets. You need this list to compute the result in the end.
- If you see a closing bracket and if the previous bracket is also a closing bracket just push it on the stack.
- If you see a closing bracket and if the previous bracket i.e. top of the stack is a non-matching opening bracket, just reset the stack because there is no way you get a balanced bracket.

After you traverse the whole sequence of brackets, you will end up in either empty list of balanced bracket tuples ( See second bullet ) or end up in one or more items in the list of balanced bracket tuples. Now you have to traverse this list to get the maximum length of balanced brackets.

For the example ()({[]}) you will get the list of tuples as :

(0, 1), (4, 5), (3, 6), (2, 7).

As you can see (2, 7) contains (4, 5), (3, 6) and it can be condensed to (0, 1), (2, 7) and these two can be merged to (0, 7) which will result in a length of 8.

I will leave the implementation details to you.

Comment: successfully implemented

Comment: @math-traveler nice!

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty stack and a max_length initialized to zero.

When processing an open bracket, add the bracket type and its index to the stack.

When processing a closing bracket at index i:

1. If the top of the stack is a matching opening bracket, remove it from the stack. Then find the index of the new top of stack, say j. Now max_length = max(max_length, i-j). Treat nil (nothing on the stack) as index -1.
2. Otherwise, add the closing bracket type and its index to the stack.

E.g. [}[]{} (I'll use bracket:index to represent the stack, for brevity)

initially, max_len = 0, stack is empty.

1. process [ at index 0: stack = [:0
2. process } at index 1: stack = [:0, }:1
3. process [ at index 2: stack = [:0, }:1, [:2
4. process ] at index 3: stack = [:0, }:1, and we update max_len = max(0, 3-1) = 2
5. process { at index 4: stack = [:0, }:1, {:4
6. process } at index 5: stack = [:0, }:1, and we update max_len = max(2, 5-1) = 4

This is linear in time & space.